# Visual Studio Data Base Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I get an error when i built a database in visual studio. I press right click at the App_Data and click Add New Item and choose SQL Server Database and then i press the add button.
I got following message box.

**Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will  be closed.**

Answer (score 0):

Found this online:

[Fix error "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance."](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/fix-error-Failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-SQL-Server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-the-process-for-the-user-instance.aspx)